# Firebug how to (For addons/extensions)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firebug, local-storage

Can anyone recommend a tutorial on how to use firebug with Firefox Addon development?

Most google and youtube searches only give me results on how to use it for webpages :(

My main requirement right now is to see and modify if my addon is saving to localstorage.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that you *can* debug chrome and XUL with Firefox... However, there's a version of Firebug meant for debugging Firefox chrome and add-ons, called "Chromebug". You may be able to find more useful information here: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Chromebug_User_Guide

Comment: Thanks! Will check it out, in the meantime if anyone else has any advise please dont be shy!

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/extension-developer/ is helpful, especially when you're just getting started, though I understand there are some issues with it on Firefox 4

Comment: Yep, it was I who mentioned it on the other thread...
Pity really, I hope the dev updates it soon.

Answer (score 0):

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Internals#How_to_write_a_Firebug_extension.3F
and more links from that page eg: http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/category/firebug/